# SELECT takes 1 second INSERT @TableVar SELECT takes 45 seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a select statement that executes sub-second on a table of 255 million rows. The result is approximately 50 rows.

When I try to do an INSERT @Tbl SELECT ..., the query takes 45 seconds.

Can someone explain this to me?

Here is the complete batch. Timer is 127 seconds. When insert line is commented out, Timer is 2 seconds.

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO


declare @fr datetime = '2013-01-01', @to datetime = '2013-09-01'
declare @TempTable table (Title varchar(50), PlayCount int, Wt float)

declare @t1 datetime = getdate()

    insert @TempTable
    select Title, PlayCount, MaxCount * 1.0 / PlayCount as Weight
    from (
        select l.SkinDescription as Title, count(*) as PlayCount, max(count(*)) OVER() AS MaxCount
        from LegalConfiguration l 
        join Play p on p.LegalConfigNumber = l.SequenceNumber
        where p.CurrentDate between @fr and @to
        group by l.SkinDescription
    ) sub

declare @t2 datetime = getdate()

select * from @TempTable
select datediff(ss,@t1,@t2) as timer
```

Comment: Without knowing how you set up your schema, we can only guess. Maybe it's an index issue? How did you setup your indexes for that column?

Comment: An insert requires a higher level lock.  Is this an active table?

Comment: The query without inserting into a table var is less than a second. The table var has no index... what index?

Comment: Table is not in use. Database is on my dev server with 1 user - me.

Comment: I just want to know why this is... I'll edit...

Comment: explain plan please and thank you.

Comment: How do I post a showplan? XML is pretty big.

Comment: Show @Tbl definition. This is strange.  Show the complete statement.

Comment: In a comment you said table valued function.  Did you mean table variable.

Comment: What exact version of SQL Server are you using?  Is it fully patched with the latest updates?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 (11.0.2218.0) all patches I know of, including the VS 2012 BI stuff.

Comment: One more thing I forgot to mention. Probably has nothing to do with the problem but explains how the query runs so fast. I'm using a columnstore index that I drop for updates and rebuild daily.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is your sub-second select is a cached result.  Whereas the Insert @Tbl Select forces a cache flush and therefore 45 seconds is closer to reality on youre time that is needed.  Also, the subsecond select implies that either all 255 million rows fit into memory or that it is partially cached and you are only returning the top N results in your copy of sql developer therefore allowing the application to page.

Comment: @Metaphor perhaps you misunderstood.  When you run the select query it caches the result at the database level.  That way it doesn't have to reexecute the full query.

Comment: I cleared the SQL Server cache with DBCC before posting the question.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - the sub-second execution could also be a result of good index utilization in the query. Possibly on top of caching.

Answer (score -1):

Table variables like `@Tbl` limit the query execution to a single thread. Change your code to use temp tables. Like so:

```
select EPSName, count(*) as PlayCount, max(count(*)) OVER() AS MaxCount
into #Tbl
from LegalConfiguration l 
join Play p on p.LegalConfigNumber = l.SequenceNumber
where p.CurrentDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
group by EPSname
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE #Tbl (EPSName VARCHAR(100),PlayCount INT, MaxCount INT)

INSERT #Tbl
select EPSName, count(*) as PlayCount, max(count(*)) OVER() AS MaxCount
from LegalConfiguration l 
join Play p on p.LegalConfigNumber = l.SequenceNumber
where p.CurrentDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
group by EPSname
```

You may also try adding an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to your original insert query.

The reason why parallelism does not work for table variables is explained  [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2008/10/09/table-variable-vs-temp-table-and-estimated-vs-actual-query-plan.aspx). This is an important excerpt from the article:

When the queries are compiled neither the table variable nor temporary table are populated and the query optimizer assumes “minimum” number of rows and that is always 1 in SQL Server. This estimation is used when SQL Server generates the “Estimated” query plan. While the “Estimated” and “Actual” query plans are same in most cases, there are some exception. If a table (temporary or permanent) is created in the same batch with the query, SQL Serve has to recompile the query since the query definition is unknown when the batch is compiled the first time. This is not the case for table variables.

Comment: Good idea. But i can't use a temp table, this needs to be in a table valued function.

Comment: Why not change it to a stored procedure? Then you can use the `INSERT - EXEC` syntax to use this data elsewhere. EG: `INSERT <tableName> EXEC myProc`

Comment: I need an inline function.

Comment: Could you share _why_ you have such a requirement? Table valued functions will always perform poorly due to limited parallelism.

Comment: This function returns a table of weighted tokens and is used in multiple places. I've re-coded the function to not use a table variable but am very curious why there is such a discrepancy in execution time when one is used.

Comment: There's not a whole lot of documentation out there motivating _why_ table variables do not produce parallel query plans in SQL Server. Try adding `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the end of your query in the table valued function. This may help performance.

Comment: may i know the reason for -1?

Comment: Silly, isn't it? About the -1 I mean. Some people just shouldn't have a right to vote!

Comment: OPTION(RECOMPILE) did not help.

Comment: Then you should try OPTION (RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 8649) as detailed in this article: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx